# Tool to load balance tasks in distributed system

Tags: performance, scheduled-tasks, load-balancing, distributed-system

I'm a bit stumped on searching for a tool to help me with a pesky load balancing problem.

Say you have a large variety of repeated hourly, daily and weekly units of code that can vary greatly in the RAM, CPU, Disk and Network usage. The usage is known and tracked fairly well.

Now say you have N servers to execute these tasks. The RAM, CPU, Disk and Network usage limits on the these servers are known as well.

What tools are available that can handle auto delegating tasks to these server in a manner that will ensure resources wont be strained?

For example (simplified):

- Task A - Consumes 20% CPU, 15GB of RAM -> Push to Server P that has 100% CPU and 32GB RAM Available
- Task B - Consumes 10% CPU, 20GB of RAM -> Server P would be Memory strained if I allocate this. Push to Server L that has 100% CPU and 32GB RAM Available
- Task C - Consumes 10% CPU, 2GB of RAM -> Push to Server P that has 80% CPU and 17GB RAM Available
- Task A - Reports finish, Server P now has 90% CPU and 30GB RAM

I feel like this is a common problem and I'm not sure why, but I'm having a heck of time finding anything in my google adventures.

It would be pretty straight forward to code something myself, but if there's already a tried and tested tool for this, why re-invent the wheel?

The closest I could find was a tool called hang fire I/O https://www.hangfire.io/overview.html
Which is somewhat close, but ignores the resource load balancing aspect of scheduling it looks like; which is key. I already have a solid scheduling system in place as it is, so this wont really help me.